# Samba server can only be accessed locally using smbclient?

Tags: networking, server, samba

I've set up a Samba server to share some files with my Windows computer. The server is up and running but somehow the shared folder can only be accessed locally with:

> smbclient //localhost/share

If I try to run the command also locally on Linux but use the binded IP address like:

> smbclient //xxx.xxx.xx.x/share

It gives an error message:

> WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
>   protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE

Here's what I did to set up the server:
in smb.conf:

> [global]
>   .... (default settings)
>   hosts allow = MY-WINDOWS-PC
>   bind interfaces only = yes
>   interfaces = lo eth0
>
> [share]
>   path = /mnt/my-share-folder/
>   valid users = my-user
>   read only = no
>   browsable = yes
>   public = no
>   writable = yes

I've also set up ufw by using:

> sudo ufw enable samba

Anyone has any ideas what I might be missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with interface binding. By removing those lines, the server worked with smbclient.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using. In the more current versions there is no such interface named "eth0". You may have an "eno1". Run ifconfig to see your interface names.

Answer (score 0):

https://websiteforstudents.com/create-private-samba-share-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/

I just followed this tutorial way back when i was making my samba share, tho make sure that your windows pc and host are on the same subnet (on win command prompt or power shell type in ipconfig and find Default gateway, make sure its the same one on your ubuntu host buy using ifconfig in terminal)

IF THEY ARE NOT ON SAME SUBNET:
Try to connect theme if that is not possible try port forwarding on ruter of the host machine 139 TCP and 455 TCP on the servers ip and than try again connecting but now using the routers wan adress on your pc.
I had the same issue, i forgot that i have another DHCP server running on a router behind the tv... Hope it helped